# What Happens when main() function does not return zero

Tags: c, operating-system

Please consider the following Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x;
    printf ("\nEnter x: ");
    scanf ("%d", &x);

    return x;
}

Output:
$Enter x: -2

$echo $?
254
```

My Question is:

The OS knows that return value of main() by executing a process P (The above code under execution) is NON-ZERO.

Does the OS does any kind of Handling in such cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has to be made clear what you are understanding by the "operating system" here.

If you look from the shell's point of view (which usually is just another userspace program anyway, and not a part of the kernel itself), the exit value of a process is used to evaluate the value of an expression and is important when doing shell programming as it is the most natural check one does after the termination of a process.

From the point of view of the kernel, the exit value of a process is largely dismissed. The kernel has to clean after the process regardless of the exit code it has returned.

Answer (score 4):

The return value actually indicates the status of program completion. A non-zero value indicates the program has been terminated abnormally. The status may be used by used by other programs, so it is always a good practice to return the actual status.

Comment: You are oversimplifying a bit. There are three values that are defined for the return of `main`: `0`, `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE`, where the first two indicate the success of the program. The interpretation of all other values are "implementation defined". On Linux for example all multiples of 256 also would indicate success, because it only looks at the lower bits of the return value.

Comment: Thanks for more clarification @JensGustedt

Answer (score 1):

Normally, when the program executes "expectedly" we return 0. If it does something it should not, we return non-zero depending upon the type of error (For this you can refer to errno manual). Now this return value is received by the "shell" under which the program was running. This return value can be accessed using "$?" in BASH. So it is purely for user's accessibility for a program ( that it ran correctly, and if not what is the error). This return value then can be used in shell scripts, etc., to make decisions whether to rerun or whatever the admin wants to do.
The kernel just cleans the user-land program.